# Warum schweben Deutsche nur auf Wolke sieben, wenn Amerikaner auf Wolke neun sind?

Tags: proverb

Eine deutsche Redewendung beschreibt ein Glücksgefühl als

> Auf Wolke sieben schweben.
>   Im siebten Himmel sein.

Im amerikanischen Sprachgebrauch gibt es auch eine Wolke, auf der man sich befindet; diese hängt aber viel höher, es ist nämlich die Wolke **neun**.

Woher kommt dieser Unterschied?

Comment: Schau [hier](http://askville.amazon.com/phrase-cloud/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=3625245), [hier](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-cloud-nine.html) und mein persönliches WTF [hier](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_meaning_of_the_idiom_%27on_cloud_9%27)

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Dein 2. Link ist sehr interessant ("cloud ten"). Magst Du daraus eine Antwort schreiben?

Comment: Nö, Takkat, sonst hätte ich das schon gemacht. Bin einfach zu faul. Außerdem, wenn schon, dann nehme ich den dritten Link als Antwort. So ein wirrer Nonsens muß gebührend gewürdigt werden :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolke_Sieben) schiebt die siebte Wolke auf  Aristoteles, während die neunte eher physikalisch (höchste mögliche Wolke) erklärt wird.

> Der Ausdruck Wolke Sieben oder siebter Himmel stammt wahrscheinlich aus der Theorie des griechischen Philosophen Aristoteles. Dieser teilte den Himmel als Plural in sieben durchsichtige Gewölbe (Schalen) ein, in die die Himmelskörper eingebettet sind. [...] Manchmal wird es auch so überliefert: Das Altertum kannte sieben Himmelssphären – auch sieben Himmel genannt. Hinter dem letzten sichtbaren Planeten Saturn, dem Hüter der Schwelle, endete die materielle Welt, und es kam nur noch die unsichtbare geistige Welt, die Welt der Phantasie, Wünsche und Träume.
>
> Im Englischen wird allerdings eher von cloud no. nine, also Wolke Nummer Neun, gesprochen. Dieses rührt angeblich daher, dass die höchsten Wolken nur acht Meilen über der Erde sein können, wenn man also neun Meilen über der Erdoberfläche ist, befindet man sich über den Wolken.

Comment: Gibt es denn vergleichbare Fälle, in denen Entfernungen, Weiten oder andere Maße in Nummern übersetzt werden? Sagt man Person No. 2 für jmd. der 2m groß ist, beispielsweise (oder irgendwas mit Fuß, Yard, Unze, Gallon oder Pfund)?

Comment: @userunknown: Unter Technikern wird das häufiger mal getan. Viele Normteile haben einen einzigen Parameter wie z.B. den Durchmesser, so dass man dann tatsächlich auf ein Gewinde M10 eine "Zehner Mutter" aufschraubt.

Comment: Eine Zehner-Mutter ist aber nicht die 10. Mutter.